# Xamarin ObservableCollection on change value from list inside DataTemplate

Tags: android, xamarin, datatemplate

I'm trying to detect changes inside a Button in a DataTemplate, I know I can get the button directly and change the value, but I need to do it like this or similar (button example: TextColor = item.IsOn ? Color .Yellow : Color. White) for another functionality such as On/Off all, or when selecting one, change the color of the text of the rest of the Buttons. Any idea? Thanks in advance!

```
ObservableCollection<NodeMCU> observaleList = new ObservableCollection<NodeMCU>( await db.GetNodeMCUsAsync() );
listView.ItemsSource = observaleList;
listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    var turnOnDeviceBtn = new Button
    {
        Padding = 0,
        Margin = new Thickness(15, 0, 0, 0),
        FontSize = 20,
        // Can I somehow do this?
        TextColor = item.IsOn ? Color.Yellow : Color.White,
        FontFamily = "FontIcons",
        Text = "\ue703",
        BackgroundColor = Color.Gray
    };

    turnOnDeviceBtn.Clicked += (o, e) =>
    {
        var deviceSelected = (NodeMCU)((Button)o).BindingContext;
        
        for ( int i = 0; i < observaleList.Count; i++ )
           observaleList[i].IsOn = false;
        
        deviceSelected.IsOn = !deviceSelected.IsOn;

        //This way is running OK
        if (deviceSelected.IsOn)
            turnOnDeviceBtn.TextColor = Color.Yellow;
        else
            turnOnDeviceBtn.TextColor = Color.White;
    };

    var grid = new Grid
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(0, 5),
        ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
        {
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(.5, GridUnitType.Star) },
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(.25, GridUnitType.Star) },
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(.25, GridUnitType.Star) }
        }
    };
    grid.Children.Add(turnOnDeviceBtn, 2, 3, 0, 1);

    return new ViewCell
    {
        View = grid
    };
});
```

### UPDATE

Okey, I did this and the first time data was loaded it worked fine with the IValueConverter. But when I update all values from the ObservableCollection or click on the template button the value in the list changes but nothing changes with the IValueConverter and the color is not updated

```
ObservableCollection<NodeMCU> observaleList = new ObservableCollection<NodeMCU>( await db.GetNodeMCUsAsync() );

BoolToColorConverter converter = new BoolToColorConverter() { OnColor = Color.Yellow, OffColor = Color.White };

turnOnDeviceBtn.SetBinding( Label.TextColorProperty, new Binding( "IsOn", BindingMode.Default, converter ) );
```

External button what updates all Datatemplate data

```
bool isAllDevicesOn = false;
turnOnAllDevices.Clicked += ( o, e ) =>
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < observaleList.Count; i++ )
    observaleList[i].IsOn = !isAllDevicesOn;

  isAllDevicesOn = !isAllDevicesOn;
};
```

And that is the IValueConverter

```
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public Color OnColor { set; get; } = Color.Yellow;

  public Color OffColor { set; get; } = Color.White;

  public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
  {
    return (bool)value ? OnColor : OffColor;
  }

  public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
  {
    return ((Color)value).Equals( OnColor );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to bind the `TextColor` to the `IsOn` property, and use an `IValueConverter` to convert the `bool` to a `Color`

Comment: [X-Forms Basic Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings) has a couple of c# binding examples. To use IValueConverter in c#, you'll use [SetBinding(BindableObject, BindableProperty, String, BindingMode, IValueConverter, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobjectextensions.setbinding?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-bindableobjectextensions-setbinding).

Comment: You can try to use the mvvm and create a color variable. And then bind it with the rest button's text color. When you click the `turnOnDeviceBtn`, you can change the value of the variable.